# Sum and Difference between numbers

Tags: math

Is it possible to find two numbers a and b such that difference between a and b is equal to sum of the digits in a and b ?
Is it possible to write a general equation for this?

Comment: This sounds like more of a mathematical problem than a programming problem. Can you clarify why/how you consider this to be a programming problem (and thus on-topic for this site)?

Comment: 10...8...00 and 10...8...20 - difference is 20, digits sum to 20, fill with as many 0s as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. A general code solution / algorithm for finding it would look like this. A mathematical solution would be be found by asking on https://math.stackexchange.com/

The below code checks all integer values between 1 and 10 for a and b

```js
let a,b;
const maxIter = 10
let solution = []
for (a = 1;a < maxIter; a++) {
  for (b = 1;b < maxIter; b++) {
    const digitsInAB = `${a}${b}`.length
    if (a-b === digitsInAB || b-a === digitsInAB)
      solution.push({a,b})
  }
}
console.log(solution)
```

```html
Is it possible to find two numbers a and b such that the difference between a and b is equal to sum of the digits in a and b ? Is it possible to write a general equation for this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:

```
def digits(n)
    ans = 0
    while n > 0 do
      ans += n % 10
      n /= 10
    end
    return ans
end
```

Now we just check the possibilities exhaustively, but assuming a <= b, and noting that b can't be much bigger than a. It can be at most one digit bigger than a, so you can check from a + d(a) + 1 up to a + d(a) + 9 * (1+count of digits in a).

```
Here we have the first few:  a + digits(a) + digits(b) = b.
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
0 + 0 + 1 = 1
0 + 0 + 2 = 2
0 + 0 + 3 = 3
0 + 0 + 4 = 4
0 + 0 + 5 = 5
0 + 0 + 6 = 6
0 + 0 + 7 = 7
0 + 0 + 8 = 8
0 + 0 + 9 = 9
9 + 9 + 2 = 20
9 + 9 + 3 = 21
9 + 9 + 4 = 22
9 + 9 + 5 = 23
9 + 9 + 6 = 24
9 + 9 + 7 = 25
9 + 9 + 8 = 26
9 + 9 + 9 = 27
9 + 9 + 10 = 28
9 + 9 + 11 = 29
18 + 9 + 3 = 30
18 + 9 + 4 = 31
18 + 9 + 5 = 32
18 + 9 + 6 = 33
18 + 9 + 7 = 34
18 + 9 + 8 = 35
18 + 9 + 9 = 36
18 + 9 + 10 = 37
18 + 9 + 11 = 38
18 + 9 + 12 = 39
27 + 9 + 4 = 40
27 + 9 + 5 = 41
27 + 9 + 6 = 42
27 + 9 + 7 = 43
27 + 9 + 8 = 44
27 + 9 + 9 = 45
27 + 9 + 10 = 46
27 + 9 + 11 = 47
27 + 9 + 12 = 48
27 + 9 + 13 = 49
36 + 9 + 5 = 50
36 + 9 + 6 = 51
36 + 9 + 7 = 52
36 + 9 + 8 = 53
36 + 9 + 9 = 54
36 + 9 + 10 = 55
36 + 9 + 11 = 56
36 + 9 + 12 = 57
36 + 9 + 13 = 58
36 + 9 + 14 = 59
45 + 9 + 6 = 60
45 + 9 + 7 = 61
45 + 9 + 8 = 62
45 + 9 + 9 = 63
45 + 9 + 10 = 64
45 + 9 + 11 = 65
45 + 9 + 12 = 66
45 + 9 + 13 = 67
45 + 9 + 14 = 68
45 + 9 + 15 = 69
54 + 9 + 7 = 70
54 + 9 + 8 = 71
54 + 9 + 9 = 72
54 + 9 + 10 = 73
54 + 9 + 11 = 74
54 + 9 + 12 = 75
54 + 9 + 13 = 76
54 + 9 + 14 = 77
54 + 9 + 15 = 78
54 + 9 + 16 = 79
63 + 9 + 8 = 80
63 + 9 + 9 = 81
63 + 9 + 10 = 82
63 + 9 + 11 = 83
63 + 9 + 12 = 84
63 + 9 + 13 = 85
63 + 9 + 14 = 86
63 + 9 + 15 = 87
63 + 9 + 16 = 88
63 + 9 + 17 = 89
72 + 9 + 9 = 90
72 + 9 + 10 = 91
72 + 9 + 11 = 92
72 + 9 + 12 = 93
72 + 9 + 13 = 94
72 + 9 + 14 = 95
72 + 9 + 15 = 96
72 + 9 + 16 = 97
72 + 9 + 17 = 98
72 + 9 + 18 = 99
90 + 9 + 1 = 100
90 + 9 + 2 = 101
90 + 9 + 3 = 102
90 + 9 + 4 = 103
90 + 9 + 5 = 104
90 + 9 + 6 = 105
90 + 9 + 7 = 106
90 + 9 + 8 = 107
90 + 9 + 9 = 108
90 + 9 + 10 = 109
99 + 18 + 3 = 120
99 + 18 + 4 = 121
99 + 18 + 5 = 122
99 + 18 + 6 = 123
99 + 18 + 7 = 124
99 + 18 + 8 = 125
99 + 18 + 9 = 126
99 + 18 + 10 = 127
99 + 18 + 11 = 128
99 + 18 + 12 = 129
108 + 9 + 3 = 120
108 + 9 + 4 = 121
108 + 9 + 5 = 122
108 + 9 + 6 = 123
108 + 9 + 7 = 124
108 + 9 + 8 = 125
108 + 9 + 9 = 126
108 + 9 + 10 = 127
108 + 9 + 11 = 128
108 + 9 + 12 = 129
117 + 9 + 4 = 130
117 + 9 + 5 = 131
117 + 9 + 6 = 132
117 + 9 + 7 = 133
117 + 9 + 8 = 134
117 + 9 + 9 = 135
117 + 9 + 10 = 136
117 + 9 + 11 = 137
117 + 9 + 12 = 138
117 + 9 + 13 = 139
126 + 9 + 5 = 140
126 + 9 + 6 = 141
126 + 9 + 7 = 142
126 + 9 + 8 = 143
126 + 9 + 9 = 144
126 + 9 + 10 = 145
126 + 9 + 11 = 146
126 + 9 + 12 = 147
126 + 9 + 13 = 148
126 + 9 + 14 = 149
135 + 9 + 6 = 150
135 + 9 + 7 = 151
135 + 9 + 8 = 152
135 + 9 + 9 = 153
135 + 9 + 10 = 154
135 + 9 + 11 = 155
135 + 9 + 12 = 156
135 + 9 + 13 = 157
135 + 9 + 14 = 158
135 + 9 + 15 = 159
144 + 9 + 7 = 160
144 + 9 + 8 = 161
144 + 9 + 9 = 162
144 + 9 + 10 = 163
144 + 9 + 11 = 164
144 + 9 + 12 = 165
144 + 9 + 13 = 166
144 + 9 + 14 = 167
144 + 9 + 15 = 168
144 + 9 + 16 = 169
153 + 9 + 8 = 170
153 + 9 + 9 = 171
153 + 9 + 10 = 172
153 + 9 + 11 = 173
153 + 9 + 12 = 174
153 + 9 + 13 = 175
153 + 9 + 14 = 176
153 + 9 + 15 = 177
153 + 9 + 16 = 178
153 + 9 + 17 = 179
162 + 9 + 9 = 180
162 + 9 + 10 = 181
162 + 9 + 11 = 182
162 + 9 + 12 = 183
162 + 9 + 13 = 184
162 + 9 + 14 = 185
162 + 9 + 15 = 186
162 + 9 + 16 = 187
162 + 9 + 17 = 188
162 + 9 + 18 = 189
171 + 9 + 10 = 190
171 + 9 + 11 = 191
171 + 9 + 12 = 192
171 + 9 + 13 = 193
171 + 9 + 14 = 194
171 + 9 + 15 = 195
171 + 9 + 16 = 196
171 + 9 + 17 = 197
171 + 9 + 18 = 198
171 + 9 + 19 = 199
189 + 18 + 3 = 210
189 + 18 + 4 = 211
189 + 18 + 5 = 212
189 + 18 + 6 = 213
189 + 18 + 7 = 214
189 + 18 + 8 = 215
189 + 18 + 9 = 216
189 + 18 + 10 = 217
189 + 18 + 11 = 218
189 + 18 + 12 = 219
198 + 18 + 4 = 220
198 + 18 + 5 = 221
198 + 18 + 6 = 222
198 + 18 + 7 = 223
198 + 18 + 8 = 224
198 + 18 + 9 = 225
198 + 18 + 10 = 226
198 + 18 + 11 = 227
198 + 18 + 12 = 228
198 + 18 + 13 = 229
207 + 9 + 4 = 220
207 + 9 + 5 = 221
207 + 9 + 6 = 222
207 + 9 + 7 = 223
207 + 9 + 8 = 224
207 + 9 + 9 = 225
207 + 9 + 10 = 226
207 + 9 + 11 = 227
207 + 9 + 12 = 228
207 + 9 + 13 = 229
216 + 9 + 5 = 230
216 + 9 + 6 = 231
216 + 9 + 7 = 232
216 + 9 + 8 = 233
216 + 9 + 9 = 234
216 + 9 + 10 = 235
216 + 9 + 11 = 236
216 + 9 + 12 = 237
216 + 9 + 13 = 238
216 + 9 + 14 = 239
225 + 9 + 6 = 240
225 + 9 + 7 = 241
225 + 9 + 8 = 242
225 + 9 + 9 = 243
225 + 9 + 10 = 244
225 + 9 + 11 = 245
225 + 9 + 12 = 246
225 + 9 + 13 = 247
225 + 9 + 14 = 248
225 + 9 + 15 = 249
234 + 9 + 7 = 250
234 + 9 + 8 = 251
234 + 9 + 9 = 252
234 + 9 + 10 = 253
234 + 9 + 11 = 254
234 + 9 + 12 = 255
234 + 9 + 13 = 256
234 + 9 + 14 = 257
234 + 9 + 15 = 258
234 + 9 + 16 = 259
243 + 9 + 8 = 260
243 + 9 + 9 = 261
243 + 9 + 10 = 262
243 + 9 + 11 = 263
243 + 9 + 12 = 264
243 + 9 + 13 = 265
243 + 9 + 14 = 266
243 + 9 + 15 = 267
243 + 9 + 16 = 268
243 + 9 + 17 = 269
252 + 9 + 9 = 270
252 + 9 + 10 = 271
252 + 9 + 11 = 272
252 + 9 + 12 = 273
252 + 9 + 13 = 274
252 + 9 + 14 = 275
252 + 9 + 15 = 276
252 + 9 + 16 = 277
252 + 9 + 17 = 278
252 + 9 + 18 = 279
261 + 9 + 10 = 280
261 + 9 + 11 = 281
261 + 9 + 12 = 282
261 + 9 + 13 = 283
261 + 9 + 14 = 284
261 + 9 + 15 = 285
261 + 9 + 16 = 286
261 + 9 + 17 = 287
261 + 9 + 18 = 288
261 + 9 + 19 = 289
270 + 9 + 11 = 290
270 + 9 + 12 = 291
270 + 9 + 13 = 292
270 + 9 + 14 = 293
270 + 9 + 15 = 294
270 + 9 + 16 = 295
270 + 9 + 17 = 296
270 + 9 + 18 = 297
270 + 9 + 19 = 298
270 + 9 + 20 = 299
279 + 18 + 3 = 300
279 + 18 + 4 = 301
279 + 18 + 5 = 302
279 + 18 + 6 = 303
279 + 18 + 7 = 304
279 + 18 + 8 = 305
279 + 18 + 9 = 306
279 + 18 + 10 = 307
279 + 18 + 11 = 308
279 + 18 + 12 = 309
288 + 18 + 4 = 310
288 + 18 + 5 = 311
288 + 18 + 6 = 312
288 + 18 + 7 = 313
288 + 18 + 8 = 314
288 + 18 + 9 = 315
288 + 18 + 10 = 316
288 + 18 + 11 = 317
288 + 18 + 12 = 318
288 + 18 + 13 = 319
297 + 18 + 5 = 320
297 + 18 + 6 = 321
297 + 18 + 7 = 322
297 + 18 + 8 = 323
297 + 18 + 9 = 324
297 + 18 + 10 = 325
297 + 18 + 11 = 326
297 + 18 + 12 = 327
297 + 18 + 13 = 328
297 + 18 + 14 = 329
306 + 9 + 5 = 320
306 + 9 + 6 = 321
306 + 9 + 7 = 322
306 + 9 + 8 = 323
306 + 9 + 9 = 324
306 + 9 + 10 = 325
306 + 9 + 11 = 326
306 + 9 + 12 = 327
306 + 9 + 13 = 328
306 + 9 + 14 = 329
315 + 9 + 6 = 330
315 + 9 + 7 = 331
315 + 9 + 8 = 332
315 + 9 + 9 = 333
315 + 9 + 10 = 334
315 + 9 + 11 = 335
315 + 9 + 12 = 336
315 + 9 + 13 = 337
315 + 9 + 14 = 338
315 + 9 + 15 = 339
324 + 9 + 7 = 340
324 + 9 + 8 = 341
324 + 9 + 9 = 342
324 + 9 + 10 = 343
324 + 9 + 11 = 344
324 + 9 + 12 = 345
324 + 9 + 13 = 346
324 + 9 + 14 = 347
324 + 9 + 15 = 348
324 + 9 + 16 = 349
333 + 9 + 8 = 350
333 + 9 + 9 = 351
333 + 9 + 10 = 352
333 + 9 + 11 = 353
333 + 9 + 12 = 354
333 + 9 + 13 = 355
333 + 9 + 14 = 356
333 + 9 + 15 = 357
333 + 9 + 16 = 358
333 + 9 + 17 = 359
342 + 9 + 9 = 360
342 + 9 + 10 = 361
342 + 9 + 11 = 362
342 + 9 + 12 = 363
342 + 9 + 13 = 364
342 + 9 + 14 = 365
342 + 9 + 15 = 366
342 + 9 + 16 = 367
342 + 9 + 17 = 368
342 + 9 + 18 = 369
351 + 9 + 10 = 370
351 + 9 + 11 = 371
351 + 9 + 12 = 372
351 + 9 + 13 = 373
351 + 9 + 14 = 374
351 + 9 + 15 = 375
351 + 9 + 16 = 376
351 + 9 + 17 = 377
351 + 9 + 18 = 378
351 + 9 + 19 = 379
360 + 9 + 11 = 380
360 + 9 + 12 = 381
360 + 9 + 13 = 382
360 + 9 + 14 = 383
360 + 9 + 15 = 384
360 + 9 + 16 = 385
360 + 9 + 17 = 386
360 + 9 + 18 = 387
360 + 9 + 19 = 388
360 + 9 + 20 = 389
378 + 18 + 4 = 400
378 + 18 + 5 = 401
378 + 18 + 6 = 402
378 + 18 + 7 = 403
378 + 18 + 8 = 404
378 + 18 + 9 = 405
378 + 18 + 10 = 406
378 + 18 + 11 = 407
378 + 18 + 12 = 408
378 + 18 + 13 = 409
387 + 18 + 5 = 410
387 + 18 + 6 = 411
387 + 18 + 7 = 412
387 + 18 + 8 = 413
387 + 18 + 9 = 414
387 + 18 + 10 = 415
387 + 18 + 11 = 416
387 + 18 + 12 = 417
387 + 18 + 13 = 418
387 + 18 + 14 = 419
396 + 18 + 6 = 420
396 + 18 + 7 = 421
396 + 18 + 8 = 422
396 + 18 + 9 = 423
396 + 18 + 10 = 424
396 + 18 + 11 = 425
396 + 18 + 12 = 426
396 + 18 + 13 = 427
396 + 18 + 14 = 428
396 + 18 + 15 = 429
405 + 9 + 6 = 420
405 + 9 + 7 = 421
405 + 9 + 8 = 422
405 + 9 + 9 = 423
405 + 9 + 10 = 424
405 + 9 + 11 = 425
405 + 9 + 12 = 426
405 + 9 + 13 = 427
405 + 9 + 14 = 428
405 + 9 + 15 = 429
414 + 9 + 7 = 430
414 + 9 + 8 = 431
414 + 9 + 9 = 432
414 + 9 + 10 = 433
414 + 9 + 11 = 434
414 + 9 + 12 = 435
414 + 9 + 13 = 436
414 + 9 + 14 = 437
414 + 9 + 15 = 438
414 + 9 + 16 = 439
423 + 9 + 8 = 440
423 + 9 + 9 = 441
423 + 9 + 10 = 442
423 + 9 + 11 = 443
423 + 9 + 12 = 444
423 + 9 + 13 = 445
423 + 9 + 14 = 446
423 + 9 + 15 = 447
423 + 9 + 16 = 448
423 + 9 + 17 = 449
432 + 9 + 9 = 450
432 + 9 + 10 = 451
432 + 9 + 11 = 452
432 + 9 + 12 = 453
432 + 9 + 13 = 454
432 + 9 + 14 = 455
432 + 9 + 15 = 456
432 + 9 + 16 = 457
432 + 9 + 17 = 458
432 + 9 + 18 = 459
441 + 9 + 10 = 460
441 + 9 + 11 = 461
441 + 9 + 12 = 462
441 + 9 + 13 = 463
441 + 9 + 14 = 464
441 + 9 + 15 = 465
441 + 9 + 16 = 466
441 + 9 + 17 = 467
441 + 9 + 18 = 468
441 + 9 + 19 = 469
450 + 9 + 11 = 470
450 + 9 + 12 = 471
450 + 9 + 13 = 472
450 + 9 + 14 = 473
450 + 9 + 15 = 474
450 + 9 + 16 = 475
450 + 9 + 17 = 476
450 + 9 + 18 = 477
450 + 9 + 19 = 478
450 + 9 + 20 = 479
459 + 18 + 13 = 490
459 + 18 + 14 = 491
459 + 18 + 15 = 492
459 + 18 + 16 = 493
459 + 18 + 17 = 494
459 + 18 + 18 = 495
459 + 18 + 19 = 496
459 + 18 + 20 = 497
459 + 18 + 21 = 498
459 + 18 + 22 = 499
477 + 18 + 5 = 500
477 + 18 + 6 = 501
477 + 18 + 7 = 502
477 + 18 + 8 = 503
477 + 18 + 9 = 504
477 + 18 + 10 = 505
477 + 18 + 11 = 506
477 + 18 + 12 = 507
477 + 18 + 13 = 508
477 + 18 + 14 = 509
486 + 18 + 6 = 510
486 + 18 + 7 = 511
486 + 18 + 8 = 512
486 + 18 + 9 = 513
486 + 18 + 10 = 514
486 + 18 + 11 = 515
486 + 18 + 12 = 516
486 + 18 + 13 = 517
486 + 18 + 14 = 518
486 + 18 + 15 = 519
495 + 18 + 7 = 520
495 + 18 + 8 = 521
495 + 18 + 9 = 522
495 + 18 + 10 = 523
495 + 18 + 11 = 524
495 + 18 + 12 = 525
495 + 18 + 13 = 526
495 + 18 + 14 = 527
495 + 18 + 15 = 528
495 + 18 + 16 = 529
504 + 9 + 7 = 520
504 + 9 + 8 = 521
504 + 9 + 9 = 522
504 + 9 + 10 = 523
504 + 9 + 11 = 524
504 + 9 + 12 = 525
504 + 9 + 13 = 526
504 + 9 + 14 = 527
504 + 9 + 15 = 528
504 + 9 + 16 = 529
513 + 9 + 8 = 530
513 + 9 + 9 = 531
513 + 9 + 10 = 532
513 + 9 + 11 = 533
513 + 9 + 12 = 534
513 + 9 + 13 = 535
513 + 9 + 14 = 536
513 + 9 + 15 = 537
513 + 9 + 16 = 538
513 + 9 + 17 = 539
522 + 9 + 9 = 540
522 + 9 + 10 = 541
522 + 9 + 11 = 542
522 + 9 + 12 = 543
522 + 9 + 13 = 544
522 + 9 + 14 = 545
522 + 9 + 15 = 546
522 + 9 + 16 = 547
522 + 9 + 17 = 548
522 + 9 + 18 = 549
531 + 9 + 10 = 550
531 + 9 + 11 = 551
531 + 9 + 12 = 552
531 + 9 + 13 = 553
531 + 9 + 14 = 554
531 + 9 + 15 = 555
531 + 9 + 16 = 556
531 + 9 + 17 = 557
531 + 9 + 18 = 558
531 + 9 + 19 = 559
540 + 9 + 11 = 560
540 + 9 + 12 = 561
540 + 9 + 13 = 562
540 + 9 + 14 = 563
540 + 9 + 15 = 564
540 + 9 + 16 = 565
540 + 9 + 17 = 566
540 + 9 + 18 = 567
540 + 9 + 19 = 568
540 + 9 + 20 = 569
549 + 18 + 13 = 580
549 + 18 + 14 = 581
549 + 18 + 15 = 582
549 + 18 + 16 = 583
549 + 18 + 17 = 584
549 + 18 + 18 = 585
549 + 18 + 19 = 586
549 + 18 + 20 = 587
549 + 18 + 21 = 588
549 + 18 + 22 = 589
558 + 18 + 14 = 590
558 + 18 + 15 = 591
558 + 18 + 16 = 592
558 + 18 + 17 = 593
558 + 18 + 18 = 594
558 + 18 + 19 = 595
558 + 18 + 20 = 596
558 + 18 + 21 = 597
558 + 18 + 22 = 598
558 + 18 + 23 = 599
576 + 18 + 6 = 600
576 + 18 + 7 = 601
576 + 18 + 8 = 602
576 + 18 + 9 = 603
576 + 18 + 10 = 604
576 + 18 + 11 = 605
576 + 18 + 12 = 606
576 + 18 + 13 = 607
576 + 18 + 14 = 608
576 + 18 + 15 = 609
585 + 18 + 7 = 610
585 + 18 + 8 = 611
585 + 18 + 9 = 612
585 + 18 + 10 = 613
585 + 18 + 11 = 614
585 + 18 + 12 = 615
585 + 18 + 13 = 616
585 + 18 + 14 = 617
585 + 18 + 15 = 618
585 + 18 + 16 = 619
594 + 18 + 8 = 620
594 + 18 + 9 = 621
594 + 18 + 10 = 622
594 + 18 + 11 = 623
594 + 18 + 12 = 624
594 + 18 + 13 = 625
594 + 18 + 14 = 626
594 + 18 + 15 = 627
594 + 18 + 16 = 628
594 + 18 + 17 = 629
603 + 9 + 8 = 620
603 + 9 + 9 = 621
603 + 9 + 10 = 622
603 + 9 + 11 = 623
603 + 9 + 12 = 624
603 + 9 + 13 = 625
603 + 9 + 14 = 626
603 + 9 + 15 = 627
603 + 9 + 16 = 628
603 + 9 + 17 = 629
612 + 9 + 9 = 630
612 + 9 + 10 = 631
612 + 9 + 11 = 632
612 + 9 + 12 = 633
612 + 9 + 13 = 634
612 + 9 + 14 = 635
612 + 9 + 15 = 636
612 + 9 + 16 = 637
612 + 9 + 17 = 638
612 + 9 + 18 = 639
621 + 9 + 10 = 640
621 + 9 + 11 = 641
621 + 9 + 12 = 642
621 + 9 + 13 = 643
621 + 9 + 14 = 644
621 + 9 + 15 = 645
621 + 9 + 16 = 646
621 + 9 + 17 = 647
621 + 9 + 18 = 648
621 + 9 + 19 = 649
630 + 9 + 11 = 650
630 + 9 + 12 = 651
630 + 9 + 13 = 652
630 + 9 + 14 = 653
630 + 9 + 15 = 654
630 + 9 + 16 = 655
630 + 9 + 17 = 656
630 + 9 + 18 = 657
630 + 9 + 19 = 658
630 + 9 + 20 = 659
639 + 18 + 13 = 670
639 + 18 + 14 = 671
639 + 18 + 15 = 672
639 + 18 + 16 = 673
639 + 18 + 17 = 674
639 + 18 + 18 = 675
639 + 18 + 19 = 676
639 + 18 + 20 = 677
639 + 18 + 21 = 678
639 + 18 + 22 = 679
648 + 18 + 14 = 680
648 + 18 + 15 = 681
648 + 18 + 16 = 682
648 + 18 + 17 = 683
648 + 18 + 18 = 684
648 + 18 + 19 = 685
648 + 18 + 20 = 686
648 + 18 + 21 = 687
648 + 18 + 22 = 688
648 + 18 + 23 = 689
657 + 18 + 15 = 690
657 + 18 + 16 = 691
657 + 18 + 17 = 692
657 + 18 + 18 = 693
657 + 18 + 19 = 694
657 + 18 + 20 = 695
657 + 18 + 21 = 696
657 + 18 + 22 = 697
657 + 18 + 23 = 698
657 + 18 + 24 = 699
675 + 18 + 7 = 700
675 + 18 + 8 = 701
675 + 18 + 9 = 702
675 + 18 + 10 = 703
675 + 18 + 11 = 704
675 + 18 + 12 = 705
675 + 18 + 13 = 706
675 + 18 + 14 = 707
675 + 18 + 15 = 708
675 + 18 + 16 = 709
684 + 18 + 8 = 710
684 + 18 + 9 = 711
684 + 18 + 10 = 712
684 + 18 + 11 = 713
684 + 18 + 12 = 714
684 + 18 + 13 = 715
684 + 18 + 14 = 716
684 + 18 + 15 = 717
684 + 18 + 16 = 718
684 + 18 + 17 = 719
693 + 18 + 9 = 720
693 + 18 + 10 = 721
693 + 18 + 11 = 722
693 + 18 + 12 = 723
693 + 18 + 13 = 724
693 + 18 + 14 = 725
693 + 18 + 15 = 726
693 + 18 + 16 = 727
693 + 18 + 17 = 728
693 + 18 + 18 = 729
702 + 9 + 9 = 720
702 + 9 + 10 = 721
702 + 9 + 11 = 722
702 + 9 + 12 = 723
702 + 9 + 13 = 724
702 + 9 + 14 = 725
702 + 9 + 15 = 726
702 + 9 + 16 = 727
702 + 9 + 17 = 728
702 + 9 + 18 = 729
711 + 9 + 10 = 730
711 + 9 + 11 = 731
711 + 9 + 12 = 732
711 + 9 + 13 = 733
711 + 9 + 14 = 734
711 + 9 + 15 = 735
711 + 9 + 16 = 736
711 + 9 + 17 = 737
711 + 9 + 18 = 738
711 + 9 + 19 = 739
720 + 9 + 11 = 740
720 + 9 + 12 = 741
720 + 9 + 13 = 742
720 + 9 + 14 = 743
720 + 9 + 15 = 744
720 + 9 + 16 = 745
720 + 9 + 17 = 746
720 + 9 + 18 = 747
720 + 9 + 19 = 748
720 + 9 + 20 = 749
729 + 18 + 13 = 760
729 + 18 + 14 = 761
729 + 18 + 15 = 762
729 + 18 + 16 = 763
729 + 18 + 17 = 764
729 + 18 + 18 = 765
729 + 18 + 19 = 766
729 + 18 + 20 = 767
729 + 18 + 21 = 768
729 + 18 + 22 = 769
738 + 18 + 14 = 770
738 + 18 + 15 = 771
738 + 18 + 16 = 772
738 + 18 + 17 = 773
738 + 18 + 18 = 774
738 + 18 + 19 = 775
738 + 18 + 20 = 776
738 + 18 + 21 = 777
738 + 18 + 22 = 778
738 + 18 + 23 = 779
747 + 18 + 15 = 780
747 + 18 + 16 = 781
747 + 18 + 17 = 782
747 + 18 + 18 = 783
747 + 18 + 19 = 784
747 + 18 + 20 = 785
747 + 18 + 21 = 786
747 + 18 + 22 = 787
747 + 18 + 23 = 788
747 + 18 + 24 = 789
756 + 18 + 16 = 790
756 + 18 + 17 = 791
756 + 18 + 18 = 792
756 + 18 + 19 = 793
756 + 18 + 20 = 794
756 + 18 + 21 = 795
756 + 18 + 22 = 796
756 + 18 + 23 = 797
756 + 18 + 24 = 798
756 + 18 + 25 = 799
774 + 18 + 8 = 800
774 + 18 + 9 = 801
774 + 18 + 10 = 802
774 + 18 + 11 = 803
774 + 18 + 12 = 804
774 + 18 + 13 = 805
774 + 18 + 14 = 806
774 + 18 + 15 = 807
774 + 18 + 16 = 808
774 + 18 + 17 = 809
783 + 18 + 9 = 810
783 + 18 + 10 = 811
783 + 18 + 11 = 812
783 + 18 + 12 = 813
783 + 18 + 13 = 814
783 + 18 + 14 = 815
783 + 18 + 15 = 816
783 + 18 + 16 = 817
783 + 18 + 17 = 818
783 + 18 + 18 = 819
792 + 18 + 10 = 820
792 + 18 + 11 = 821
792 + 18 + 12 = 822
792 + 18 + 13 = 823
792 + 18 + 14 = 824
792 + 18 + 15 = 825
792 + 18 + 16 = 826
792 + 18 + 17 = 827
792 + 18 + 18 = 828
792 + 18 + 19 = 829
801 + 9 + 10 = 820
801 + 9 + 11 = 821
801 + 9 + 12 = 822
801 + 9 + 13 = 823
801 + 9 + 14 = 824
801 + 9 + 15 = 825
801 + 9 + 16 = 826
801 + 9 + 17 = 827
801 + 9 + 18 = 828
801 + 9 + 19 = 829
810 + 9 + 11 = 830
810 + 9 + 12 = 831
810 + 9 + 13 = 832
810 + 9 + 14 = 833
810 + 9 + 15 = 834
810 + 9 + 16 = 835
810 + 9 + 17 = 836
810 + 9 + 18 = 837
810 + 9 + 19 = 838
810 + 9 + 20 = 839
819 + 18 + 13 = 850
819 + 18 + 14 = 851
819 + 18 + 15 = 852
819 + 18 + 16 = 853
819 + 18 + 17 = 854
819 + 18 + 18 = 855
819 + 18 + 19 = 856
819 + 18 + 20 = 857
819 + 18 + 21 = 858
819 + 18 + 22 = 859
828 + 18 + 14 = 860
828 + 18 + 15 = 861
828 + 18 + 16 = 862
828 + 18 + 17 = 863
828 + 18 + 18 = 864
828 + 18 + 19 = 865
828 + 18 + 20 = 866
828 + 18 + 21 = 867
828 + 18 + 22 = 868
828 + 18 + 23 = 869
837 + 18 + 15 = 870
837 + 18 + 16 = 871
837 + 18 + 17 = 872
837 + 18 + 18 = 873
837 + 18 + 19 = 874
837 + 18 + 20 = 875
837 + 18 + 21 = 876
837 + 18 + 22 = 877
837 + 18 + 23 = 878
837 + 18 + 24 = 879
846 + 18 + 16 = 880
846 + 18 + 17 = 881
846 + 18 + 18 = 882
846 + 18 + 19 = 883
846 + 18 + 20 = 884
846 + 18 + 21 = 885
846 + 18 + 22 = 886
846 + 18 + 23 = 887
846 + 18 + 24 = 888
846 + 18 + 25 = 889
855 + 18 + 17 = 890
855 + 18 + 18 = 891
855 + 18 + 19 = 892
855 + 18 + 20 = 893
855 + 18 + 21 = 894
855 + 18 + 22 = 895
855 + 18 + 23 = 896
855 + 18 + 24 = 897
855 + 18 + 25 = 898
855 + 18 + 26 = 899
873 + 18 + 9 = 900
873 + 18 + 10 = 901
873 + 18 + 11 = 902
873 + 18 + 12 = 903
873 + 18 + 13 = 904
873 + 18 + 14 = 905
873 + 18 + 15 = 906
873 + 18 + 16 = 907
873 + 18 + 17 = 908
873 + 18 + 18 = 909
882 + 18 + 10 = 910
882 + 18 + 11 = 911
882 + 18 + 12 = 912
882 + 18 + 13 = 913
882 + 18 + 14 = 914
882 + 18 + 15 = 915
882 + 18 + 16 = 916
882 + 18 + 17 = 917
882 + 18 + 18 = 918
882 + 18 + 19 = 919
891 + 18 + 11 = 920
891 + 18 + 12 = 921
891 + 18 + 13 = 922
891 + 18 + 14 = 923
891 + 18 + 15 = 924
891 + 18 + 16 = 925
891 + 18 + 17 = 926
891 + 18 + 18 = 927
891 + 18 + 19 = 928
891 + 18 + 20 = 929
900 + 9 + 11 = 920
900 + 9 + 12 = 921
900 + 9 + 13 = 922
900 + 9 + 14 = 923
900 + 9 + 15 = 924
900 + 9 + 16 = 925
900 + 9 + 17 = 926
900 + 9 + 18 = 927
900 + 9 + 19 = 928
900 + 9 + 20 = 929
909 + 18 + 13 = 940
909 + 18 + 14 = 941
909 + 18 + 15 = 942
909 + 18 + 16 = 943
909 + 18 + 17 = 944
909 + 18 + 18 = 945
909 + 18 + 19 = 946
909 + 18 + 20 = 947
909 + 18 + 21 = 948
909 + 18 + 22 = 949
918 + 18 + 14 = 950
918 + 18 + 15 = 951
918 + 18 + 16 = 952
918 + 18 + 17 = 953
918 + 18 + 18 = 954
918 + 18 + 19 = 955
918 + 18 + 20 = 956
927 + 18 + 16 = 961
927 + 18 + 17 = 962
927 + 18 + 18 = 963
927 + 18 + 19 = 964
927 + 18 + 20 = 965
927 + 18 + 21 = 966
927 + 18 + 22 = 967
927 + 18 + 23 = 968
927 + 18 + 24 = 969
936 + 18 + 16 = 970
936 + 18 + 17 = 971
936 + 18 + 18 = 972
936 + 18 + 19 = 973
936 + 18 + 20 = 974
936 + 18 + 21 = 975
936 + 18 + 22 = 976
936 + 18 + 23 = 977
936 + 18 + 24 = 978
936 + 18 + 25 = 979
945 + 18 + 17 = 980
945 + 18 + 18 = 981
945 + 18 + 19 = 982
945 + 18 + 20 = 983
945 + 18 + 21 = 984
945 + 18 + 22 = 985
945 + 18 + 23 = 986
945 + 18 + 24 = 987
945 + 18 + 25 = 988
945 + 18 + 26 = 989
954 + 18 + 18 = 990
954 + 18 + 19 = 991
954 + 18 + 20 = 992
954 + 18 + 21 = 993
954 + 18 + 22 = 994
954 + 18 + 23 = 995
954 + 18 + 24 = 996
954 + 18 + 25 = 997
954 + 18 + 26 = 998
954 + 18 + 27 = 999
981 + 18 + 1 = 1000
981 + 18 + 2 = 1001
981 + 18 + 3 = 1002
981 + 18 + 4 = 1003
981 + 18 + 5 = 1004
981 + 18 + 6 = 1005
981 + 18 + 7 = 1006
981 + 18 + 8 = 1007
981 + 18 + 9 = 1008
981 + 18 + 10 = 1009
990 + 18 + 2 = 1010
990 + 18 + 3 = 1011
990 + 18 + 4 = 1012
990 + 18 + 5 = 1013
990 + 18 + 6 = 1014
990 + 18 + 7 = 1015
990 + 18 + 8 = 1016
990 + 18 + 9 = 1017
990 + 18 + 10 = 1018
990 + 18 + 11 = 1019
999 + 27 + 4 = 1030
999 + 27 + 5 = 1031
999 + 27 + 6 = 1032
999 + 27 + 7 = 1033
999 + 27 + 8 = 1034
999 + 27 + 9 = 1035
999 + 27 + 10 = 1036
999 + 27 + 11 = 1037
999 + 27 + 12 = 1038
999 + 27 + 13 = 1039
```